# R code for Kutner et al's Applied Linear Statistical Models?

Tags: r, regression, self-study, references

I am self-studying [Applied Linear Statistical Models by Michael Kutner, Christopher Nachtsheim, John Neter, William Li](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007310874X).

Is there R code for the methods in the book?

Comment: If you mean is there a package geared to the book, the authors would surely document it. If you mean can you do most or all of what is done in the book through R, the answer is surely yes, but I doubt anyone will list the R packages available for regression/linear models.

Comment: Yes, I meant the first. But if there are alternatives close enough, they are fine too.

Comment: @NickCox Regarding the authors documenting code - not necessarily. I remember one book (I think it is Agresti's Categorical Data Analysis but am not sure) where someone else wrote code for the whole book.

Comment: I don't think Agresti's an exception any longer. But I agree that you are right in principle: there could be exceptions.

Comment: I doubt there's such a thing. But for each thing you want to do, there's a good chance there's already R code to do it.

Answer (score 4):

There is an excellent package called [car](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/index.html) based on the book [An R Companion to Applied Regression](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/141297514X). Check out this [website](http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/scripts.html) for R scripts. This book is a good companion for Kutner et. al.

Answer (score 2):

I think all the code examples in the book are in SAS/JMP. Btw, Kutner et al. is one amazing book!

Answer (score 2):

ALSM: Companion to Applied Linear Statistical Models

Functions and Data set presented in Applied Linear Statistical Models Fifth Edition (Chapters 1-9 and 16-25)

https://cran.r-project.org/package=ALSM

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above all the examples in the book are from SAS, JMP, and Minitab. The data files, however, are available online as text files so importing them into R isn't a problem (I've done it with a few of the example myself). There's no reason why you can't just replicate the examples in R using just the lm, aov, and Anova (from the car package) functions. Or you can follow the guidelines in the book to do things the long way round (decomposing the sums of squares individually by computing consecutive lm model fits and summing the squared residuals, for example).